# Using toString function on my .sol file and then solc.compile to compile it produces an error

Tags: node.js, windows, ethereum, solidity, truffle

I recently started using [this course on Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/course/getting-started-with-ethereum-solidity-development/) to learn more about blockchain technologies and smart contracts. The main problem is that this course is based on older versions of solidity, truffle, geth, node.js etc. and therefore it is difficult to follow sometimes. Other people have posted my issue in the Q&A section but I don't think it has been solved so I'm trying here. I only have background in Python 3, C and C++.

I first run `sourceCode = fs.readFileSync('Greetings.sol').toString()` and get the following:

```
  '\r\n' +
  'contract Greetings {\r\n' +
  '    string message;\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  '    constructor(){\r\n' +
  `        message = "I'm ready";\r\n` +
  '    }\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  '    function setGreetings(string memory _message) public {\r\n' +
  '        message = _message;\r\n' +
  '    }\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  '    function getGreetings() public view returns (string memory){\r\n' +
  '        return message;\r\n' +
  '    }\r\n' +
  '}'
```

Then I run `compiledCode = solc.compile(sourceCode)` and get

```
'{"errors":[{"component":"general","formattedMessage":"* Line 1, Column 1\\n  Syntax error: value, object or array expected.\\n* Line 1, Column 2\\n  Extra non-whitespace after JSON value.\\n","message":"* Line 1, Column 1\\n  Syntax error: value, object or array expected.\\n* Line 1, Column 2\\n  Extra non-whitespace after JSON value.\\n","severity":"error","type":"JSONError"}]}'
```

From what I understand it is not in the correct format for it to be compiled. How do I resolve this?

I have the most recent versions of Geth, Truffle, Web3, Solc, Node.js etc. and any libraries. The Solc I have installed is the same as the one in the `pragma` statement. I code using VS Code with the Solidity extension and use Windows Powershell for executing the commands.

My Grettings.sol file:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED


pragma solidity ^0.8.15;


contract Greetings {
    string message;

    constructor(){
        message = "I'm ready";
    }

    function setGreetings(string memory _message) public {
        message = _message;
    }

    function getGreetings() public view returns (string memory){
        return message;
    }
}
```

Full log:

```
> sourceCode = fs.readFileSync('Greetings.sol').toString()
'pragma solidity ^0.8.15;\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  'contract Greetings {\r\n' +
  '    string message;\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  '    constructor(){\r\n' +
  `        message = "I'm ready";\r\n` +
  '    }\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  '    function setGreetings(string memory _message) public {\r\n' +
  '        message = _message;\r\n' +
  '    }\r\n' +
  '\r\n' +
  '    function getGreetings() public view returns (string memory){\r\n' +
  '        return message;\r\n' +
  '    }\r\n' +
  '}'
> compiledCode = solc.compile(sourceCode)
'{"errors":[{"component":"general","formattedMessage":"* Line 1, Column 1\\n  Syntax error: value, object or array expected.\\n* Line 1, Column 2\\n  Extra non-whitespace after JSON value.\\n","message":"* Line 1, Column 1\\n  Syntax error: value, object or array expected.\\n* Line 1, Column 2\\n  Extra non-whitespace after JSON value.\\n","severity":"error","type":"JSONError"}]}'
```

Comment: how about modifying the parsing like `var output = solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input));` instead of using the toString(), also please refer the [github page](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js) in github, they are passing in a configuration object into the compile function!

Comment: @NarenMurali Thank you! That was very helpful! Any ideas as to how I collect the abi and bytecode data from this output variable?

Comment: @NarenMurali nevermind I found it. Now I'm trying to create a contract using the compiled byteCode and ABI so that I can deploy my contract.

In the course it mentions to create an object of type ContractFactory and he uses `greetingsContract. = web3.eth.contract(contractABI)` to create that object. I used `greetingsContract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI)` but it's not of that data type. Can you help me with this or should I make another post? He then uses this code `greetingsDeployed = greetingsContract.new({data:byteCode, from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 47000000})` to deploy it.

Comment: another post would be best

Comment: please answer this question yourself and close this issue! or edit this same question with the new doubt

Comment: okay! I'll add what I did to solve it and mark it as solved. @NarenMurali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the help in the comments and the link they posted I have figured it out and will post the commands I used to move on to the next steps. I am stuck somewhere else now so I'll make another post for that.

```
sourceCode = fs.readFileSync('Greetings.sol').toString()
```

Convert the text in the .sol file to a string

```
input = {language: 'Solidity', sources: {['Greetings.sol']: {content: sourceCode}},settings:{outputSelection:{'*':{'*':['*']}}}}
```

Set it as an input in the correct JSON format

```
output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)))
```

Convert input to JSON string, compile it with the solc compiler, and parse it to a new variable.

```
contractABI = output.contracts['Greetings.sol']['Greetings'].abi
byteCode = output.contracts['Greetings.sol']['Greetings'].evm['bytecode'].object
```

Collect the ABI and bytecode data and store them into variables.