# How do I create a smart contract instance and interact with my smart contract functions?

Tags: node.js, windows, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I am studying a [course on Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/course/getting-started-with-ethereum-solidity-development/) to learn more about blockchain technologies and smart contracts. This course is based on older versions of solidity, truffle, geth, node.js etc. so most of the code written is outdated. I don't have a background in Javascript so I'm learning as I go.

So far I have written and ran this code line by line with no issues:

```
Web3 = require('web3')
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:7545"))
accounts = web3.eth.getAccounts()
solc = require('solc')
sourceCode = fs.readFileSync('Greetings.sol').toString()
input = {language: 'Solidity', sources: {['Greetings.sol']: {content: sourceCode}},settings:{outputSelection:{'*':{'*':['*']}}}} 
output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)))
contractABI = output.contracts['Greetings.sol']['Greetings'].abi
byteCode = output.contracts['Greetings.sol']['Greetings'].evm['bytecode'].object
account0 = (await web3.eth.getAccounts())[0]
greetingsContract = new web3.eth.Contract([contractABI])
greetingsDeployed = greetingsContract.deploy({data: '0x' + byteCode}).send({from: account0, gas: 6721975, gasPrice: 1})
```

I know exactly what almost each line does but I'm at a loss as to how I will interact with my functions I've written in my 'Greetings.sol' file. The contracts appear in Ganache as contract creations with the byteCode I'm sending. In the course he mentions to use `greetingsInstance = greetingsContract.at(greetingsDeployed.address)` but that is outdated. So finally, how do I create a smart contract instance and interact with my functions?

Below I have posted my `greetingsContract`, `greetingsDeployed` and `contractABI` variables for more info.

**greetingsContract:**

```
Contract {
  setProvider: [Function (anonymous)],
  currentProvider: [Getter/Setter],
  _requestManager: RequestManager {
    provider: HttpProvider {
      withCredentials: false,
      timeout: 0,
      headers: undefined,
      agent: undefined,
      connected: true,
      host: 'http://localhost:7545',
      httpAgent: [Agent]
    },
    providers: {
      WebsocketProvider: [Function: WebsocketProvider],
      HttpProvider: [Function: HttpProvider],
      IpcProvider: [Function: IpcProvider]
    },
    subscriptions: Map(0) {}
  },
  givenProvider: null,
  providers: {
    WebsocketProvider: [Function: WebsocketProvider],
    HttpProvider: [Function: HttpProvider],
    IpcProvider: [Function: IpcProvider]
  },
  _provider: HttpProvider {
    withCredentials: false,
    timeout: 0,
    headers: undefined,
    agent: undefined,
    connected: true,
    host: 'http://localhost:7545',
    httpAgent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 80,
      protocol: 'http:',
      options: [Object: null prototype],
      requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
      sockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
      freeSockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: true,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      scheduling: 'lifo',
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 0,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    }
  },
  setRequestManager: [Function (anonymous)],
  BatchRequest: [Function: bound Batch],
  extend: [Function: ex] {
    formatters: {
      inputDefaultBlockNumberFormatter: [Function: inputDefaultBlockNumberFormatter],
      inputBlockNumberFormatter: [Function: inputBlockNumberFormatter],
      inputCallFormatter: [Function: inputCallFormatter],
      inputTransactionFormatter: [Function: inputTransactionFormatter],
      inputAddressFormatter: [Function: inputAddressFormatter],
      inputPostFormatter: [Function: inputPostFormatter],
      inputLogFormatter: [Function: inputLogFormatter],
      inputSignFormatter: [Function: inputSignFormatter],
      inputStorageKeysFormatter: [Function: inputStorageKeysFormatter],
      outputProofFormatter: [Function: outputProofFormatter],
      outputBigNumberFormatter: [Function: outputBigNumberFormatter],
      outputTransactionFormatter: [Function: outputTransactionFormatter],
      outputTransactionReceiptFormatter: [Function: outputTransactionReceiptFormatter],
      outputBlockFormatter: [Function: outputBlockFormatter],
      outputLogFormatter: [Function: outputLogFormatter],
      outputPostFormatter: [Function: outputPostFormatter],
      outputSyncingFormatter: [Function: outputSyncingFormatter]
    },
    utils: {
      _fireError: [Function: _fireError],
      _jsonInterfaceMethodToString: [Function: _jsonInterfaceMethodToString],
      _flattenTypes: [Function: _flattenTypes],
      randomHex: [Function: randomHex],
      BN: [Function: BNwrapped],
      isBN: [Function: isBN],
      isBigNumber: [Function: isBigNumber],
      isHex: [Function: isHex],
      isHexStrict: [Function: isHexStrict],
      sha3: [Function],
      sha3Raw: [Function: sha3Raw],
      keccak256: [Function],
      soliditySha3: [Function: soliditySha3],
      soliditySha3Raw: [Function: soliditySha3Raw],
      encodePacked: [Function: encodePacked],
      isAddress: [Function: isAddress],
      checkAddressChecksum: [Function: checkAddressChecksum],
      toChecksumAddress: [Function: toChecksumAddress],
      toHex: [Function: toHex],
      toBN: [Function: toBN],
      bytesToHex: [Function: bytesToHex],
      hexToBytes: [Function: hexToBytes],
      hexToNumberString: [Function: hexToNumberString],
      hexToNumber: [Function: hexToNumber],
      toDecimal: [Function: hexToNumber],
      numberToHex: [Function: numberToHex],
      fromDecimal: [Function: numberToHex],
      hexToUtf8: [Function: hexToUtf8],
      hexToString: [Function: hexToUtf8],
      toUtf8: [Function: hexToUtf8],
      stripHexPrefix: [Function: stripHexPrefix],
      utf8ToHex: [Function: utf8ToHex],
      stringToHex: [Function: utf8ToHex],
      fromUtf8: [Function: utf8ToHex],
      hexToAscii: [Function: hexToAscii],
      toAscii: [Function: hexToAscii],
      asciiToHex: [Function: asciiToHex],
      fromAscii: [Function: asciiToHex],
      unitMap: [Object],
      toWei: [Function: toWei],
      fromWei: [Function: fromWei],
      padLeft: [Function: leftPad],
      leftPad: [Function: leftPad],
      padRight: [Function: rightPad],
      rightPad: [Function: rightPad],
      toTwosComplement: [Function: toTwosComplement],
      isBloom: [Function: isBloom],
      isUserEthereumAddressInBloom: [Function: isUserEthereumAddressInBloom],
      isContractAddressInBloom: [Function: isContractAddressInBloom],
      isTopic: [Function: isTopic],
      isTopicInBloom: [Function: isTopicInBloom],
      isInBloom: [Function: isInBloom],
      compareBlockNumbers: [Function: compareBlockNumbers],
      toNumber: [Function: toNumber]
    },
    Method: [Function: Method]
  },
  clearSubscriptions: [Function (anonymous)],
  options: {
    address: [Getter/Setter],
    jsonInterface: [Getter/Setter],
    data: undefined,
    from: undefined,
    gasPrice: undefined,
    gas: undefined
  },
  handleRevert: [Getter/Setter],
  defaultCommon: [Getter/Setter],
  defaultHardfork: [Getter/Setter],
  defaultChain: [Getter/Setter],
  transactionPollingTimeout: [Getter/Setter],
  transactionPollingInterval: [Getter/Setter],
  transactionConfirmationBlocks: [Getter/Setter],
  transactionBlockTimeout: [Getter/Setter],
  blockHeaderTimeout: [Getter/Setter],
  defaultAccount: [Getter/Setter],
  defaultBlock: [Getter/Setter],
  methods: {},
  events: { allEvents: [Function: bound ] },
  _address: null,
  _jsonInterface: [
    [
      [Object],
      [Object],
      [Object],
      constant: undefined,
      payable: undefined
    ]
  ]
}
```

**greetingsDeployed:**

```
Promise {
  Contract {
    setProvider: [Function (anonymous)],
    currentProvider: [Getter/Setter],
    _requestManager: RequestManager {
      provider: [HttpProvider],
      providers: [Object],
      subscriptions: Map(0) {}
    },
    givenProvider: null,
    providers: {
      WebsocketProvider: [Function: WebsocketProvider],
      HttpProvider: [Function: HttpProvider],
      IpcProvider: [Function: IpcProvider]
    },
    _provider: HttpProvider {
      withCredentials: false,
      timeout: 0,
      headers: undefined,
      agent: undefined,
      connected: true,
      host: 'http://localhost:7545',
      httpAgent: [Agent]
    },
    setRequestManager: [Function (anonymous)],
    BatchRequest: [Function: bound Batch],
    extend: [Function: ex] {
      formatters: [Object],
      utils: [Object],
      Method: [Function: Method]
    },
    clearSubscriptions: [Function (anonymous)],
    options: {
      address: [Getter/Setter],
      jsonInterface: [Getter/Setter],
      data: undefined,
      from: undefined,
      gasPrice: undefined,
      gas: undefined
    },
    handleRevert: [Getter/Setter],
    defaultCommon: [Getter/Setter],
    defaultHardfork: [Getter/Setter],
    defaultChain: [Getter/Setter],
    transactionPollingTimeout: [Getter/Setter],
    transactionPollingInterval: [Getter/Setter],
    transactionConfirmationBlocks: [Getter/Setter],
    transactionBlockTimeout: [Getter/Setter],
    blockHeaderTimeout: [Getter/Setter],
    defaultAccount: [Getter/Setter],
    defaultBlock: [Getter/Setter],
    methods: {},
    events: { allEvents: [Function: bound ] },
    _address: '0xD41D42E01d6ceDa1A96028Ae8bc89b45723DBD8A',
    _jsonInterface: [ [Array] ]
  },
  _events: Events <[Object: null prototype] {}> {},
  emit: [Function: emit],
  on: [Function: on],
  once: [Function: once],
  off: [Function: removeListener],
  listeners: [Function: listeners],
  addListener: [Function: on],
  removeListener: [Function: removeListener],
  removeAllListeners: [Function: removeAllListeners],
  _eventsCount: 0,
  [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 17341,
  [Symbol(trigger_async_id_symbol)]: 5,
  [Symbol(destroyed)]: { destroyed: false }
}
```

**contractABI:**

```
[
  {
    inputs: [],
    stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
    type: 'constructor',
    constant: undefined,
    payable: undefined
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: 'getGreetings',
    outputs: [ [Object] ],
    stateMutability: 'view',
    type: 'function',
    constant: true,
    payable: undefined,
    signature: '0xca4c3a41'
  },
  {
    inputs: [ [Object] ],
    name: 'setGreetings',
    outputs: [],
    stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
    type: 'function',
    constant: undefined,
    payable: undefined,
    signature: '0x49da5de4'
  },
  constant: undefined,
  payable: undefined
]
```

**Greetings.sol/Solidity code:**

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity ^0.8.15;

contract Greetings {
    string message;

    constructor(){
        message = "I'm ready";
    }

    function setGreetings(string memory _message) public {
        message = _message;
    }

    function getGreetings() public view returns (string memory){
        return message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These both tutorials were great resources for solving your problem!

1. [Creating & Deploying a Smart Contract using Web3js & Ganache-CLI — Part 1](https://medium.com/coinmonks/get-started-with-building-ethereum-dapps-and-smart-contracts-d86b9f7bd1c)
2. [Interacting with a Smart Contract through Web3.js (Tutorial)](https://medium.com/@yangnana11/interacting-with-a-smart-contract-through-web3-js-tutorial-56a7ff2ff153)

Also PFB reference code which works. Mistakes are:

1. ABI should not be inside an array.

   const notorizedContract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI);
2. await is not working in the global scope for me, so I have gone with `then` to resolve the response, could be due to node version, but this worked for me!

solidity part (NotarizeDocument.sol)

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity ^0.8.15;

contract NotarizedDocument {
    
    mapping (bytes32 => bool) documentProof;
    
    function notarize(string memory document) public {
        bytes32 signedDocument = signDoc(document);
        storeDocumentProof(signedDocument);
    }
    
    function signDoc(string memory document) private pure returns (bytes32) {
        return sha256(abi.encodePacked(document));
    }
    
    function storeDocumentProof(bytes32 signedDocument) private {
        documentProof[signedDocument] = true;
    }
    
    function checkDocument (string memory document) public view returns (bool) {
        bytes32 signedDocument = signDoc(document);
        return hasProof(signedDocument);
    }
    
    function hasProof(bytes32 signedDocument) private view returns (bool) {
        return documentProof[signedDocument];
    }
}
```

javascript part

```
var Web3 = require("web3");
var fs = require("fs");
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
var accounts = web3.eth.getAccounts();
var solc = require("solc");
var sourceCode = fs
  .readFileSync(`${__dirname}/contracts/NotarizeDocument.sol`)
  .toString();
var input = {
  language: "Solidity",
  sources: { ["NotarizeDocument.sol"]: { content: sourceCode } },
  settings: { outputSelection: { "*": { "*": ["*"] } } },
};
var output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));
var contractABI =
  output.contracts["NotarizeDocument.sol"].NotarizedDocument.abi;
var byteCode =
  output.contracts["NotarizeDocument.sol"].NotarizedDocument.evm["bytecode"]
    .object;
const notorizedContract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI);
web3.eth.getAccounts().then((accounts) => {
  var account0 = accounts[0];
  notorizedContract
    .deploy({ data: "0x" + byteCode })
    .send({ from: account0, gas: 6721975, gasPrice: 1 })
    .then(async (newContractInstance) => {
      notorizedContract.options.address = newContractInstance.options.address;
      const response = await notorizedContract.methods
        .notarize("Hello Romil!!")
        .send({ from: "0x7B7DB1E2b197aDa733326381513f12639F5e0Ecb" });
      // completed transaction!
      console.log(response);
      await notorizedContract.methods
        .checkDocument("Hello Romil!!")
        .call(console.log);
    });
});
```

The second response returns true, which means the text exists!

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It all worked but now I'm trying to get the transaction hash when I input data using my `setGreetings()` function. I can see it in Ganache in the entry with the contract call tag but how would I get it outputed in powershell? The code I use to set the value in powershell is `greetingsContract.methods.setGreetings("hi friend").send({from: account0}).then(function(transactionHash){}`. I also updated my question with the solidity code.

Comment: @Yiannis please console.log the variable transactionHash inside the then block, you will see it in the terminal, if you primary issue is resolved please mark this question as closed

Comment: I don't understand. Can you please explain more clearly which code I change? @NarenMurali

Comment: @YiannisMichael `greetingsContract.methods.setGreetings("hi friend").send({from: account0}).then(function(transactionHash){console.log(transactionHash);}`

Comment: Thank you again! I will paste here the code I used since your code is much more detailed than what was required to do but it helped me.
`greetingsContract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI)`
`greetingsDeployed = greetingsContract.deploy({data: '0x' + byteCode}).send({from: account0, gas: 6721975, gasPrice: 1}).then((greetingsInstance) => {greetingsContract.options.address=greetingsInstance.options.address});`
`greetingsContract.methods.getGreetings`
`greetingsContract.methods.setGreetings("hi friend").send({from: account0})`

Comment: Apologies as I do not know JS but this outputs it to the powershell. How would I go about storing this transaction hash in a variable? @NarenMurali

Comment: @YiannisMichael I'm sorry but as my understand your running a javascript code using the command `node test.ts` if we do console.log in javascript it will be outputted to the powershell window, If you are using the node command

Comment: Yes it does. I want to store the transaction hash in a variable/object as a string. Apologies if I am not using the right terminology. It is outputed in the powershell and I can confirm it is correct but I would like to know how to store it somewhere. @NarenMurali

Comment: @YiannisMichael Seems more like a powershell question now, could you please ask the question again in the powershell tag section of stack overflow, because javascript is my speciality and I was assuming everthing in the question needed to be done in JS

Comment: no I believe it is a JS question since it would require JS code to work. So I am getting this output. When using the code you sent I get this:

`greetingsContract.methods.setGreetings("hi friend").send({from: account0}).then(function(transactionHash){console.log(transactionHash)})
Promise {
  <pending>,
  [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 582,
  [Symbol(trigger_async_id_symbol)]: 566,
  [Symbol(destroyed)]: { destroyed: false }
}
> {
  transactionHash: '0xa6f1198d5633b707967460a268323e84db71776c18daeef9fbf336049c9e2327',
....}`

My question is how do I retrieve that value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246439/discussion-between-naren-murali-and-yiannis-michael).

Answer (score 0):

If you`re using Hardhat toolbox or new ethers.js v6, you may do this:

```
const { abi } = require("../artifacts/contracts/YourContractFile.sol/YourContractName.json")
const [Signer] = await ethers.getSigners()
const contractAddress = "0xabcd..."
const ContractInstance = new ethers.BaseContract(contractAddress, abi, Signer)
```

So now you are allowed to call your Contract`s methods like this:

```
const result = await ContractInstance.yourFunction(yourArgs))
console.log(result)
```

And you want to reuse same ContractInstance but with different address, try attach method:

```
const newContractAddress = "0xdbca..."
const result = await ContractInstance.attach(newContractAddress).yourFunction(yourArgs)
```